# iOS: UITableviewController is not updating the value of one label

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a tableview with custom cell and it has 2 labels, I am changing the tab and view controller Programatically I have called `[tablview reloadData]` after updating my list. But it is just updating one **label** value. here is the code of **cellForRowAtIndexPath**:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    TimesheetCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TimesheetCell"];
    Timesheet *t = (self.timesheetArray)[indexPath.row];
    cell.timesheetTitle.text = t.date;

    cell.hours.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", t.hours];
    NSLog(@"%d", t.hours);

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    formatter.dateFormat = @"EEEE, MMMM d";
    NSString *currentDate = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSLog(@"%@",t.date);
    if([t.date isEqualToString:currentDate]){
        cell.timesheetTitle.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.478431 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];
        cell.hours.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.478431 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];
    }
    if(_changeCellToBlack)
    {
        cell.timesheetTitle.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1.0];
        cell.hours.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0];
    }

    if (indexPath.row == 7) {

        [cell.timesheetTitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Black" size:19]];
        [cell.hours setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Black" size:19]];

        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
        if (t.hours < 40) {
            cell.timesheetTitle.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
            cell.hours.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

**Hours label is not updating its value, I have logged value from list it contains the value of hour.**

Comment: Show us how do you add `hours` UILabel to the cell.

Comment: I am using Table view controller and I have a custom class for cell `TimesheetCell` and I have created an IBOutlet property of hours label.

Comment: what is exact problem ? hour label not getting text ?

Comment: It is getting text but it is not showing on table view I don't know what's the problem because it is setting the text in **cellForRowAtIndexPath** but not showing in table view.

Comment: `cell.hours.text = hour;` 
In this line of code `hour` has the values but it is not showing on tableview.

Comment: that might be the problem in connecting control to cell class...

Comment: @Sneha My date label is updating according to the requirement but hours are not updating can you please guide me where is the actual problem?

Comment: Is `cell.hours` nil?

Comment: @Larme Nups it is not nil..

Comment: You seem to change the color of the label, does it works? What's its frame?

Comment: just disconnect IBOutlet of that Label & connect that again.. This problem arises many times in customcell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending 4 hours I have found the issue. Issue was in my code just change the alpha of `cell.hours.textColor`, just changed this line:

`cell.hours.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1.0];`